# How to show white border around text in android as image below pragrammatically?

Tags: android

show white border around text in android as programmatically in which each letter corners should be white and the middle should be red and yellow.!

[Exactly As in the Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKDAd.png)

Answer (score 0):

Create an image with the text using an external tool like Gimp or Photoshop.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: I extended the answer. Maybe I did not express myself properly, but the thing is that he will have to create an image containing the text externally and then add it to his project drawable resources.

Answer (score 0):

Find a Font (let's call it custom.font in here) who work like this, and then you use this custom font with your textview, edittext or something else

Put it in the assets folder (in a fonts folder to be specific)

> assets/fonts/custom.font

Create the custom TypeFace with your font

```
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/custom.font");
```

And set it to a TextView

```
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview);
tv.setTypeface(tf);
```